# AWS CLI executing in wrong regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-regions

My AWS profile is configured to default to eu-west-1, however when I run an AWS CLI command, it is executing in us-east-1:

```
>aws configure get region
eu-west-1

>aws events put-rule --name hourly_trigger --schedule-expression "rate(60 minutes)"
{ 
  "RuleArn": "arn:aws:events:us-east-1:588237033746:rule/hourly_trigger"
}
```

I've looked into profiles and config options and can't determine why this is.  My profile is set as follows:

```
[default]
region = eu-west-1
```

And this command works in the intended region if I add --region

```
>aws events put-rule --name hourly_trigger --schedule-expression "rate(60 mi
nutes)" --region eu-west-1
{
    "RuleArn": "arn:aws:events:eu-west-1:588237033746:rule/hourly_trigger"
}
```

Comment: What does your ~/.aws/config file look like?  Do you have the same result when you include --region eu-west-1 in your aws cli?

Comment: I've edited the question to include this - the only setting is region = eu-west-1

Comment: And does it work if you add --region eu-west-1  in your aws cli command?

Comment: Yes - question updated again.  Adding --region is the workaround I've been using for now until I solve this.

Comment: I would not call adding `--region` a workaround as IMO it is always better to explicitly specify what region you are targeting with your CLI command.

Comment: And does it work by setting the ENV var? export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=eu-west-1

Seems like your config file is not readable, but since aws configure get region works, that seems strange. (or there is a bug in the aws cli itself. What version of aws cli are you on?)

Comment: And there it is. AWS_DEFAULT_REGION was set to us-east-1. I thought I checked that. Thanks Thomas!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AWS Region is obtained through three ways:

1. Checks if your command contains --region
2. If not specified, Checks the env variable AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
3. If that is not set, it checks the region defined in the ~/.aws/config file

Make sure AWS_DEFAULT_REGION is not set. Then it should automatically use the region defined in the config file.