# aws s3: Extra charge against us-east-1 when putting to ap-northeast-1

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

Our AWS statement came in and we noticed we're being doubly charged for the number of requests.

First charge is for `Asia Pacific (Tokyo)` (*ap-northeast-1*) and this is straightforward because it's where our bucket is located.  But there's another charge against `US East (N. Virginia)` (*us-east-1*) with a similar number of requests.

Long story short, it appears this is happening because we're using the [`aws s3` command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/) and we haven't specified a region either via the `--region` option or [any of the fallback methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51287114/1036728).

Typing `aws configure list` shows `region: Value=<not set> Type=None Location=None`.

And yet our `aws s3` commands succeed, albeit with this seemingly hidden charge.  The presumption is, our requests first go to *us-east-1*, but since there isn't a bucket there by the name we specified, it turns around and comes back to *ap-northeast-1*, where it ultimately succeeds while getting accounted twice.

The ec2 instance where the `aws` command is run is itself in *ap-northeast-1* if that counts for anything.

So the question is, is the presumption above a reasonable account of what's happening?  (i.e. Is it expected behaviour.)  And, it seems a bit insidious to me but is there a proper rationale for this?

Comment: I don't know the answer and now you asked I would like to. Perhaps just contact AWS support? They'll no doubt be happy to answer this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is correct. The `aws s3` command needs to know the region in order to access the S3 bucket.

Since this has not been provided, it will make a request to `us-east-1`, which is effectively the default - see the [AWS S3 region chart](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region) to see that `us-east-1` does not require a location constraint.

If the S3 receives a request for a bucket which is not in that region then it returns a [PermanentRedirect](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html) response with the correct region for the Bucket. The AWS CLI handles this transparently and repeats the request with the correct endpoint which includes the region.

The easiest way to see this in action is to run commands in debug mode:

```
aws s3 ls ap-northeast-1-bucket --debug
```

The output will include:

```
DEBUG - Response body:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>PermanentRedirect</Code><Message>The bucket you are attempting to access 
must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to 
this endpoint.</Message>
<Endpoint>ap-northeast-1-bucket.s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com</Endpoint>
<Bucket>ap-northeast-1</Bucket> 
<RequestId>3C4FED2EFFF915E9</RequestId><HostId>...</HostId></Error>
```

The AWS CLI does not assume the Region is the same as the calling EC2 instance, it's a [long running confusion/feature request](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/486).

Additional Note: Not all AWS services will auto-discover the region in this way and will fail if the Region is not set. S3 works because it uses a Global Namespace which inherently requires some form of discovery service.